# rmarkdown::render prompts error while "Knit to html" button runs. Need to knit from within a script

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have a sample RMD below. When using `render` from rmarkdown package, I get an error:

```
Quitting from lines 25-27 (TRY1.Rmd) 
Error in select(., UID, Homework_10, Exam_3, Section) : 
  unused arguments (UID, Homework_10, Exam_3, Section)
```

while when i use the `knit to html` button, it works. What might be the issue? This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58687351/rmarkdownrender-prompts-error-while-knit-to-html-button-runs) but the other question is unanswered. Tried the few suggestions to no avail. Note that the dataframe `gradebook` contains very many variables. Thanks for your help

---

````
---
title: uuu
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
library(dplyr)
```


```{r}
set.seed(1)
gradebook <- data.frame(
  UID = sample(100000000:999999999, size = 150, replace = FALSE),
  Homework_10 = sample(0:100, size = 150, replace = TRUE),
  Exam_3 = sample(0:100, size = 150, replace = TRUE),
  Section = c(rep('A',times = 80),rep('B', times = 70)))
```


```{r}
gradebook[c(1,2,3,81,82,83),] %>% 
  select(UID, Homework_10, Exam_3, Section)
```
````

---

Comment: does it work when you use `dplyr::select` ?

Comment: On my Windows computer, both methods work without error message.

Comment: Try base R, `gradebook[c(1, 2, 3, 81, 82, 83), c("UID", "Homework_10", "Exam_3", "Section")]`

Comment: @jay.sf. Have a lot of scripts and all the students use select.

Comment: @RonakShah. That is the solution!! One student loads the MASS package, and it seems that my function does not unload it. These causes all the other scripts not to knit. Thanks so much. You could add that as a solution

Comment: Should it be marked as duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202120/dplyrselect-function-clashes-with-massselect Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46325145/error-with-select-function-from-dplyr ? Or you still think I should add an answer?

Comment: @RonakShah technically it should not be as a duplicate. Many will search the issue not realizing that it is a clash. If I knew it was a clash, I wouldnot have asked. I know at times you could search and get duplicates, although I would prefer to have you answer it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was `dplyr::select` was masked with `MASS::select` which resulted in error.

Possible ways to overcome this issue are

1. Restart R and load only `dplyr` library.
2. Use `dplyr::select` instead of just `select`.